# show $v(A) \le v(B)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I think I might have a handle on this one, but I wanted confirmation. So here is the question.

If $A$ and $B$ are contented sets with $A \subset B$, use the fact that if $f$ and $g$ are admissible functions on $R^n$ with $f \le$ everywhere and $A$ is a contented set then,$\int_A f \le \int_A g$ with $f = \varphi_A = \varphi_B \varphi_A$, $g = \varphi_B$ to show that $v(A) \le v(B)$.

$\varphi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$

I think i need to use the fact that $\int \varphi_A = v(A)$ and since $f \le g$ their integrals hold the same relation and therefore it follows that $v(A) \le v(B)$.

It seems too simple for this class..... anyway thanks for taking a look.

Comment: What is a 'contented set'? What is an 'admissible function'? I suspect there is a language barrier at work here.

Comment: I tried googling for "contented set", but this question itself was the third hit. Doesn't look like standard terminology.

Comment: contented set means "has content" and an admissible functions satisfy these properties: a) $f$ is bounded b) $f$ has bounded support and c) $f$ is continuous except on a negligible set

Comment: I dont know why I need to know that $\varphi_A = \varphi_B \varphi_A$, that's my biggest concern

Comment: What does it mean for a set to have content? Do you mean that it has positive measure?

Comment: Page 214 of Edwards has the definition: http://books.google.com/books?id=sZIFcJ8DJAIC&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=contented+set&source=bl&ots=OgJQWgEdTn&sig=lC5tD0Mygm915LI-a6Oqi2tlI4c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZDNeUcGoBorB2wXY54HYBA&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=contented%20set&f=false